# Entering coordinates of 2D points using the keyboard

Tags: data, input

I am studying the singular points of a triangle. I need to get the vertices of the triangle and then work with them.

I have worked with the function `Input`, but I don't see how to make it work for a point coordinate data type.

What is shown below is intended to get the there sides of a triangle,

```
x = {};
n = 3;
k >= 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, 
  br = Input[Row[{"Entre el  lado ", FromCharacterCode[k + 64]}]];
  AppendTo[x, br];]
a = x[[1]];
b = x[[2]];
c = x[[3]];
```

I need something like the above, but modified to accept the coordinates of 3 points, $A: (x1, y1)$, $B: (x2, y2)$ and $C: (x3, y3)$  After the points are entered I want to be able to work freely with $x1,\, y1,\, x2,\, y2,\, x3,\, y3$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: should work. you need to key in the points in mathematica notation. `{0,0}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work pretty much as-is, but it can made cleaner.

```
{a, b, c} =
  Module[{pts = {}, pt, n = 3, vars},
    vars = Take[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], n];
    For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
      pt = 
        Block[{x, y}, Input[Row[{"Enter vertex ", vars[[k]]}], Style[{x, y}, "Input", 14]]];
      AppendTo[pts, pt]];
    pts]
```

But the above code isn't very robust. You must be very careful to type in pairs like `{42, 73}` or you could get nonsense assigned to your variables `a`, `b`, `c`.

To make things more robust it would be a good idea write a function that not only accepts input but validates it. Here is an example.

```
getPt[name_String] :=
  Module[{pt},
    While[True,
      pt = 
        Block[{x, y}, Input[Row[{"Enter vertex ", name}], Style[{x, y}, "Input", 14]]];
      If[MatchQ[pt, $Canceled | {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}], Return[pt]]]]

getPt["A"]
```

[image: input-1]

[image: input-2]

> ```
> {42, 3.14}
> ```

This function will reject all input that doesn't match the pattern `{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}`. Input satisfying this pattern will be lists of two numeric elements, the normal *Mathematica* representation of 2D points. The function also allows the user to cancel out of the input dialog.

To use this function is quite simple. simpler in fact than using a For-loop.

```
{a, b, c} =
  Module[{n = 3, vars},
    vars = Take[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], n];
    getPt /@ vars]
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant using `InputString` to avoid having to key in the `{` brackets..

```
  (While[! MatchQ[in = ToExpression[
       "{" <> InputString["enter point: " <> #] <> "}"],
           {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}]]; in) & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}
```